# Supremum Sum of Exp(1) is Poi(λ )

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

Let $(E_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ be independent exp(1) random variables. 
Show that for 
$$N:=\sup\left\{n\in\mathbb{N}:\sum_{i=0}^n E_i \leq \lambda\right\},$$
we have $N \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$.

What I have so far:

Sum of exp(1) = gamma(k,1). My problem with this problem is I am unsure how to eliminate the supermum and condition it such that it will become

[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. Show that
   $$\begin{align*} \mathbb{P}(N=k) &= \mathbb{P} \left( \sum_{i=0}^k  E_i \leq \lambda, \sum_{i=0}^{k+1} E_i>\lambda \right) \\ &= \int_{(0,\infty)}\! \ldots\! \int_{(0,\infty)} e^{-\sum_{j=0}^{k} x_j} 1_{[0,\lambda]}(x_0+\ldots+x_{k-1}) 1_{(\lambda,\infty]}(x_0+\ldots+x_k) \, dx_k \ldots dx_0. \end{align*}$$
2. Conclude that $$\mathbb{P}(N=k) = e^{-\lambda} \int_{(0,\infty)} \ldots \int_{(0,\infty)} 1_{[0,\lambda]}(x_0+\ldots+x_{k-1}) \, dx_{k-1}\, \ldots \, dx_0. \tag{1}$$
3. Find either a geometric interpretation for the integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ or use a proof by induction to show that $$\int_{(0,\infty)} \ldots \int_{(0,\infty)} 1_{[0,\lambda]}(x_0+\ldots+x_{k-1}) \, dx_{k-1} \, \ldots \, dx_0 = \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}.$$

Comment: Mmmhm, at the moment this is still a bit too high level for me. Is there anyway you can further elaborate on the hints? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Ah never mind, I figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: @user3225528 You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Define a sequence of random variables $$S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n E_i, \quad n = 1, 2, \ldots. $$  Then the event $N = n$ is equivalent to saying $$S_{n} \le \lambda < S_{n+1},$$ which is in turn equal to $$S_n \le \lambda < S_n + E_{n+1}.$$  Since $S_n$ and $E_{n+1}$ are independent, it follows from the law of total probability that $$\Pr[N = n] = \int_{s=0}^\lambda \Pr[E_{n+1} > \lambda - s] f_{S_n}(s) \, ds.$$  Then since $S_n \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(n,1)$, we have 
$$\Pr[N = n] = \int_{s=0}^\lambda e^{-(\lambda-s)} \frac{s^{n-1} e^{-s}}{\Gamma(n)} \, ds = e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}.$$  The details of this last computation is left as a straightforward exercise for the reader.